# An expression for section of leg just above the ankle

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, expressions, nouns

Correct me If I'm wrong - As far as I understand, the ankle is the region where the foot and the leg meet or the bone/bump right above the heel.

Is there a single word or a simple expression for a section of the leg right above the ankle?

For example, I would like to say: 
'She decorated her wrists with golden rings and her [...] with bracelets (or other item).

Do I just say 'ankles' or 'lower shins' instead, or is there a relatively better/more accurate way to describe the action?

I like how the first solution sounds, but I'm not sure If it's accurate and while the second solution sounds more accurate (to me), I don't like how it sounds.

Comment: Does the word [anklet](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anklet) help?

Comment: "calf" --------

Comment: @Pam A bit, but the used decoration is supposed to be like a cuff bracelet, so/and I might want to change the used word. It would be nicer to know the word that relates to section of the leg.

Comment: @GregLee Isn't calf, like behind the leg and right under the knee? I'm not sure If it's the word I'm looking for. If it is, could you elaborate on the meaning, please?

Comment: I'd just go for "ankle".

Comment: A bracelet/anklet would be worn round the ankle, meaning the narrow part between the calf and the foot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just the *lower leg*. The front part of it is the *shin* and the upper half of the back part of it is the *calf*.

The word *shank* was historically used for this but sounds very old fashioned today.

But usually if someone wears bracelets there we say they're worn on the ankle instead of the leg. They may even be called *anklets* instead of bracelets.